# How to properly set a plugin's options using an object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm almost ashamed to ask.. but can't seem to figure this one out..

Normally it's done like so...

```
instance_name = $("#select-field").magicSuggest({
        valueField: 'id',
        displayField: 'title',            
        maxSelection: 1
    });
```

I wanted to make it like so.. so i can make a function out of it...

```
options ={ 
           valueField: 'id',
           displayField: 'title',            
           maxSelection: 1
         };

instance_name = $("#select-field").magicSuggest(options);
```

I tried this and there are no errors, but it doesnt work..

fiddled: http://jsfiddle.net/B6Gtm/6/

Comment: Those two should be exactly the same.

Comment: Do you actually have an object called `#select-field`, are you _sure_ there are no errors, etc. This code looks fine (except that you are missing some `var` keywords.)

Comment: i know right?!but doesnt work.. options don't get set , atleast for this magicsuggest plugin it didnt.. been scratching my head ...

Comment: Fiddle or didn't happen!

Comment: @Mathletics , pretty sure mate.. this thing works , i just copy and pasted the options part out of the initiation part of the code.. and doesn't work after.. didnt change any selector or nuthin.

Comment: You need to show the surrounding code and the HTML as many factors can stop JS code working :)

Comment: wait..lemme try and fiddle this..

Comment: right.. fiddled it, updated the post..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've put your initialisation in a function where you have redefined the variable `options` so it is scoped to that function, but you've not passed in your options

```
options = {    
    data: ['Paris', 'New York', 'Japan'],
    valueField: 'id',
    displayField: 'name',
    hideTrigger: true,
    maxSelection: 1
};
function doMe(options){

    var instance_name2 = $("#select-field2").magicSuggest(options);
}
doMe();
```

So your two examples are by no means the same, if they were then it would work fine. Demonstrated here by making the 2 the same: http://jsfiddle.net/B6Gtm/7/

So this works:

```
options = {    
    data: ['Paris', 'New York', 'Japan'],
    valueField: 'id',
    displayField: 'name',
    hideTrigger: true,
    maxSelection: 1
};
var instance_name2 = $("#select-field2").magicSuggest(options);
```

as does

```
options = {    
    data: ['Paris', 'New York', 'Japan'],
    valueField: 'id',
    displayField: 'name',
    hideTrigger: true,
    maxSelection: 1
};
function doMe(options){

    var instance_name2 = $("#select-field2").magicSuggest(options);
}
doMe(options);
```